# Magento cloud setup install failure

Tags: composer, magento2.4.3, magento-cloud, composer-update, composer-install

I am trying to install magento in magento cloud.

To do so I did:

- check out https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud
- setup auth.json
- setup env:COMPOSER_AUTH in the project with same values stored in auth.json
- pushed everything in a separate branch called staging in the magento cloud environment

However the composer install does not work.
In the cloud and in my local machine I got

```
W:   [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                                                                  
W:   The "https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-staging-page-builder/magento-module-staging-page-builder-1.7.0.0-patch1.zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
In my local pc (with php 7.4) i have different issues (they turn based on the composer install run).
```

I tried also with `composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org` in local but all I got was different error messages:

```
The "https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-banner/magento-module-banner-101.2.3.0.zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 404 )  
The "https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-invitation/magento-module-invitation-100.4.2.0.zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 404 )  
The "https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-banner-customer-segment/magento-module-banner-customer-segment-100.4.1.0.zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 404 )  
The "https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-invitation/magento-module-invitation-100.4.2.0.zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 404 )
```

With composer update i have

```
- Root composer.json requires magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.4.3, found magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.4.3] in the lock file but not in remote repositories, make sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share them? 
composer --version and php --version

Comment: PHP 7.4.27
Composer 2.2.6

Answer (score 1):

Some steps ahead were made but still unable to run composer.

Now it returns this error:

```
W:   [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                           
W:   The 'https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-staging-page-builder/magento-module-staging-page-builder-2.2.1.0.zip' URL required authentication.
W:   You must be using the interactive console to authenticate
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The error `file could not be downloaded` occurred mostly for the following two reasons.

1. Invalid auth keys.
2. Enterprise/Cloud license expired.

Also, Magento cloud by default will hand over with default Magento 2 setup without sample data.

Create a support ticket to [Magento cloud support](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us) if you have not issue with auth keys.

Comment: Hi, I cannot open a ticket a support.magento.com, I only have exchange support and they do not offer technical support.